# Excution timeout error while create image by php and imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I need create captcha from server side. I use php+imagick extension. Sometimes I find 500 error while create a image, although it works fine most of time.
The code is something like below:

```
$Imagick = new Imagick();
$Imagick->newImage( $w, $h, $bg );

$ImagickDraw = new ImagickDraw();
$ImagickDraw->setFont(...);
$ImagickDraw->setFontSize( ... );
$ImagickDraw->setFillColor(...);

$Imagick->borderImage('black', 1, 1);
$Imagick->annotateImage($ImagickDraw, 12, 34, $angles[rand(0, count($angles)-1)], $code);
$Imagick->swirlImage( 10 );

for($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
  $ImagickDraw->line( mt_rand( 1, $w-1 ), mt_rand(1, $h-1), mt_rand(1, $w-1), mt_rand(1, $h-1) );
}

for ($i=0; $i<30; $i++) {
  $ImagickDraw->color( mt_rand(1, $w-1), mt_rand(1, $h-1), 0);
}

$Imagick->drawImage( $ImagickDraw );
```

The error log reports "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" at the last line

```
$Imagick->drawImage( $ImagickDraw ).
```

Did anyone ever meet such a problem? I use php5.2.17,imagick module 2.3.0 and Apache 2.2.15.

Comment: Well, how big is the image that it's timing out on?

Comment: Is this code in a loop or are you just generating one image?

Comment: Just one image, when it works,the generated image is about 1-2k. The image is 100x40 pixels

Answer (score 1):

It means your host is killing the server process (likely after 30 seconds of execution, which would be their limit). Your script applies some filters, and on very large images this could certainly take more than 30 seconds. Consider limiting the image resolution.